# How can I install this non-PyPi python package?

Tags: python

I need to install this python package, but apparently it's not in PyPi. Is there a way to install it and use its capabilities?

As of now I only know basic operations in Python, but I'm working on it.

Thank you.

edit: this package https://github.com/hayesla/SMARTPython

Comment: What is `this python package`? Which?

Comment: What format is the package in? You can typically use wheel or setuptools if pip isn't possible

Comment: I had misplaced the link, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the packages source code. Then run:

```
pip install -e <PACKAGE_DIRECTORY>
```

or alternatively in the package directory:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Should probably prefer `pip install .` these days.

Comment: True. Thanks I added that